# What's the alternative to trying to inherit static methods?

Tags: c#, object-oriented, inheritance, static-methods

I know you can't inherit static methods, and it seems the consensus is that if you feel like you need to, you're doing something wrong.

However, I don't know what the alternative is in my case. Please see the abstract example below:

```
public abstract class A
{
    protected static int defaultX;    
    public int x = defaultX;
    
    public static abstract void Initialize()
    {
        // Read defaultX from file / API call, something expensive.
        defaultX = GetDefaultX(GetType().name)
        // I know 'GetType()' doesn't work in static methods - pretend it does.
    }
}

public abstract class B : A
{
    protected static int defaultY;    
    public int y = defaultY;
    
    public static override void Initialize()
    {
        base.Initialize()
        defaultY = GetDefaultY(class.name)
    }
}

// Then, have many classes that inherit from this, which could all
// get their default values using the above defined static methods.
class Apple : B {}
Apple.Initialize()
class Banana : B {}
Banana.Initialize()
// ...
```

Obviously this doesn't compile because you can't have abstract / inherited / overridden static methods, but it gets the point across of what I'm trying to do. Assume for the code that all static members can be inherited.

There would also be some other abstract class `C : A` that also has lots of child classes, that might have different setup variables.

What is the alternative here? To me it seems like a nice way to spread class setup code across children.

Comment: The real question is : How do you expect this code to be used? What kind of contstraints on creation are you trying to impose here? Are you trying to simplify code which creates instances? Optimize performance by using only single instance?

Comment: @Euphoric I just want default values for every instance of a class that can be changed externally. e.g. there will be a "Banana.json" file that contains `{"x": 3, "y": 7}` or something. `Banana` will be instantiated many times, I don't want to read the default values from the file every time I do it.

Comment: So cache the values from the JSON in memory.

Comment: @AndrewDean Your description of what you want already doesn't match your hypothetical code. You want "Banana.json" to specify a default value for `x`, which means "Apple.json" probably has its own `x`, but you can have only a single global default `x` since it's a single shared value in the base class. First, be clear (to yourself) about what you want.

Comment: @SebastianRedl yes, I know, that's precisely the issue. I want every subclass to have it's own static variable `x` but they are shared. I mentioned one should assume all static members are inherited when reading the code.

Comment: Factory pattern is the way to go then.

Comment: Using the name of a derived type in a static method like you attempt makes no sense. There might not be any derived classes, or multiple. There can only be one `defaultX`, so what do you expect `GetType().name` to be? The only thing that make sense is `A`, since that is the only thing you are sure exists, and for that you can just use `nameof(A)`.

Comment: Does C# have static blocks like Java?  They execute when the class is loaded.  I'm not sure but that seems like it would fit your needs here.

Comment: I don't see any reason you need `Initialize` at all. Just do your setup in the constructor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The core issue you are facing is object creation/initialization. There are several standard patterns for dealing with this:

- Inversion of control - use a framework to construct the objects for you.
- Factory Pattern - Initialize the factory, with the defaults and then use the factory to construct the objects.
- Builder pattern - Mentioned for completeness, but it may be cumbersome to manage loading defaults into builders, as builders tend to have shorter lifespans than factories.

A commonality of all of these approaches is that you would add additional parameters to the constructors of all of these classes, to pass in the initial values of `x` and `y` - they are not really "defaults" (with respect to the new instance) since they are only used to initialize the value of these properties during construction.

I am guessing that you didn't want to do this, since it seems to be a fairly obvious way to avoid using static variables and methods. So instead of adding multiple parameters to every class, you could create a `Configuration` object which is loaded/initialized from the JSON file, with the defaults for all the other classes. This might be a simple flat object or a more complex structure - with sub configuration classes corresponding to each of the abstract classes to be initialized.

It would then only be necessary to pass the `Configuration` object to each of the constructors. Those constructors can extract the specific defaults that they need, hence this solution would be compatible with all 3 of the approaches listed at the beginning of this answer.

Disclaimer: I don't code in C# so there may be a language specific option(s) I am not aware of.

Comment: Yeah, something like a `Configuration` object as a static member of the base class `A` that all subclasses could then read from was my backup option, just doesn't seem as "tidy" as having each class know store their own defaults themselves. So there is really no way to do it tidily without adding extra boilerplate to every class requiring an extra parameter?

Comment: @AndrewDean: you say it does not seem to be "as "tidy". I think this is a misconception. When you try to hide default initialization by a file or API inside a class, you make it impossible to unit test this class (and I mean "real" unit tests, where the class can be tested in isolation). When you make the access to the default parameters explicit, you can easily implement a test with hardcoded test data for the class alone, and you can test the file access to the default parameters separately. This looks a lot more tidier to me than a design which hides such file access somewhere deep inside.

Comment: The concept of "Tidy" is probably opinionated and/or not well defined. However I rarely need to use a value loaded from a configuration file as a "default" (i.e. a value that I change both in the config file and using code). In short, I don't think it happens frequently enough to be a burden from a typing and/or maintenance perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> What is the alternative here?

```
public A BuildAWithX() 
{
    int x = GetDefaultX(A.GetType().name)
    return new A(x);
}
```

Yawn.

Comment: I don't really understand what this is doing. Wouldn't this just return an instance of `A` when I'm trying to make an instance of `Banana`? And you're making the expensive `GetDefaultX()` call which is what I'm trying to avoid.

Comment: Write a version of this for Banana. `GetDefaultX` can be cached with a [dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.dictionary-2?view=net-8.0) that maps strings to ints. Each key only needs to be populated once.

Answer (score 1):

Is there any reason you aren't using static constructors (aka class constructors) instead of the overridden `static Initialize()` methods? While it is illegal to override a static non-constructor method, every class can have a static constructor. A static constructor takes no arguments and is of course marked `static`.

Having a static constructor for a class is not quite an override. C# ensures that before the class constructor for a child class is called, the static constructors for parent classes are called, all the way up the inheritance tree. C# also ensures that a static constructor is only called once.

Comment: IMHO not a bad idea in general, however, using a static constructor to initialize values from a file or API can easily become problematic. File access or API access can fail and may require a dedicated error handling in an application context later than when the static constructors are run. That may be a lot easier to be implemented when the initialization is called explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Why call `base.Initialize`? You know what your base class is. Just call `A.Initialize`.

That said, it would probably be better to use actual static initializers for this sort of thing rather than force your user to remember to call `Initialize` on everything (because they won’t). Static constructors are fine, though my experience is that initializers would make it clearer how `defaultX` is populated.

And in general “many child classes” is undesirable.